# VB Calling Parent form's Methods in a usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

control that contains a button. the user control is placed on my main form. when the button on the user control is clicked I need to to call a method that is located in the mainform.vb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call a method in the parent form, instead you raise an event which the parent form has a handler for. [Here is a real simple example](http://dotnet.itags.org/webcontrols/78031/) of what you do. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/7b31456e-e3fd-4110-98b9-be354ba1ebb5), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/da644c90-7255-456c-8624-a10569bdc196) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/98e8bb9a-86c7-49f5-a2e7-a0c3347ca569) are a few more related examples.

Answer (score 1):

simply define the method as public and call it from any form...